# How would I write the Regex for this?

Tags: c#, regex

If I have this string:

```
18.62 PURCHASE REF 1 829400493183
```

All I want to pull out is the `18.62`. How would I do that without getting the rest of the string? (For instance, without getting the `829400493183`.

If it would be easier to do this without using regex I am open to suggestion as well.

Marked as C# also because this is going into an application I am working on.

Comment: If you want do it with regex then use `@"\S+"`

Comment: did you want the first number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be done without RegEx, assuming that `18.62` is separated by a space from the rest:

```
string s = "18.62 PURCHASE REF 1 829400493183";
string r = s.Split()[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different solution, as you don't really need `Split` for this:

```
var str = "18.62 PURCHASE REF 1 829400493183";
var value = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(' '));
```

By the way, the Regex solution would look something like this:

```
var str = "18.62 PURCHASE REF 1 829400493183";
var value = Regex.Match(str, @"^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)").Value;
```

This validates the number but is still overkill as a simple `int.TryParse` will do the job.

You just need to add error checks (`IndexOf` returning -1, `Match` returning `null`).

Comment: Upvote on the fact that the Substring doesn't create, who knows, how many strings without need.. If the format is so fixed (number at start, followed by space), substring is better approach than split.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like op wants the first number rather than first word. If yes then use the below regex and get the first number from group index 1.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)");
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/11)